# Do code points(not the actual storage) from 0-255 in extended ASCII represent identical characters in Unicode?

Tags: character-encoding

Through reading wikis related to encodings, I have the understanding that `utf8` is backwards compatible with `ascii`.

`ascii` uses 7 bits to represent codepoints from 0-127. Thus ascii tells us the codepoints and also a way to store them.

`unicode` on the other hand just gives us the codepoints and the way to store them is left to formats like `utf8` and `utf16`.

Now I understand that `unicode` code points from 0-127 represent the same characters in `ascii` as well.

Next I read that there is `extended ascii` as well and it comes in various flavours like `isoLatin1` and `isoLatin2` where codepoints from 128-255 are defined as per the flavour being used.

So far so good.

Now lets get back to `unicode`. Do unicode codepoints from 128-255 represent characters exactly identical to those represented by any one of the extended ascii flavours? If so which one?

Again I could be wrong please correct me if I am wrong.

**NOTE**: I tried printing the characters and took the manual route of checking them out, but there is a chance of human error and also some characters are control characters and wont print as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The codes from 0 to 255 were choose to be compatible with ASCII and Latin-1. This was selected by design.

Note: There could be some changes on meaning, in the control character (e.g. for new lines you may get just one character).

Unicode was designed to be also a ISO standard, so it was inspired by other ISO standards (e.g. latin-1). "*Extended ASCII*" is a bad notation. I'm not sure it was ever standardized, Like ANSI (for character set, not the association).

I recommend you to stop guessing and look, e.g. in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1  I think reading such pages (and comparing) it will give you much more understanding of Unicode.

Comment: Yes. I think "extended ASCII" was just an informal way of saying _"an encoding that has ASCII as the lower 128 chars"_ (in contrast to, say, EBCDIC), rather than an official definition.

Comment: @MrLister exactly that is the reason I got confused. Extended ASCII is vague and covers more then one encodings. ISO Latin 1 and ISOLatin2 are two different encodings where the range 128-255 represents  two different char sets. When unicode is referenced I always read its backward compatible to ASCII. This was good,  but then how does it treat the range from 128-255. Is it similar to ISOLatin1 or ISOLatin2. From this answer from Giacomo could we say unicode is backward compliant with ISOLatin1?

Comment: Yeah. There were a sort of "ANSI": defines some characters but not all from 128 to 255. The other characters are locally defined (e.g. US, Western Europe, ...). ISO added control additional characters and standardized what should be used on the missing. Unicode started from Latin1 (ISO 8859 + ISO 8859-1), and it extended to 65535 character codes (and later it added "planes", so more characters code). All characters in well recognized encoding (until around 1993) should be (per design) included in Unicode

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi from you answer now I have a better understanding. If Codepoints are considered i.e 0-255 Unicode is actually identical with ISOLatin1(ASCII + Standardised extended ASCII) and not only identical to plain ASCII. On the other hand the format utf8 conforming to Unicode, is also identical to ISOLatin if Codepoints are considered. if you take into consideration the storage format  utf8 is only compatible with ASCII as it requires one byte to store codepoints ranging from 0-127. 128 onwards utf8 stores characters in 2 bytes and is not compatible to ISOLatin considering storage.

Comment: "storage format" is "encoding". UTF-8 is invented much later then Unicode. Unicode gives "every character" a numerical code. Encoding then transform the code to a binary representation for the machine. Originally Unicode planed that 16bits were enough for all characters. So early adopter (Microsoft, JavaScrips, Python) used the 2 byte per characters [and `wchar` on C become trendy]. When Unicode start thinking expanding, a encode compatible with ASCII were invented (UTF-7), but then better UTF-8 (and UTF-16: also this is now variable lenght).

Comment: The first 32 characters after 128 where control character in Latin1 (and not very used), so not useful to have these plain. At the end it matter: simple design, autorecover (UTF-8, UTF-7 was not able to recover from wrong byte), compactness (Asian UTF-8 should not take too many bytes). There were many choices. UTF-8 was a good design, and arbitrary chosen (really it was invented by Unix designers, so they pushed on Unix, and so...)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi My bad if I stated it in ambiguous way. I know utf8 came after unicode was defined, if stated correctly I wanted to know if unicode codepoints from 0-255 have the same characters as ISOLatin1 codepoints.

Comment: Yes. (I put just an explanation). Easy to convert from Latin1. "Encoding" discussion entered much later in Unicode. Latin1 was (I think) choose because it was 1 (so already "preferred" by ISO compared the Latin2 etc.)